# google sheet query with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets

Thank you to take your time reading me.

I need some help on a Query fonction.. The idea is to sum up my other sheets in one, and per month. I've alreaedy set up things to sum the total my month with this formula :

=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(bd,"SELECT SUM(I) WHERE YEAR(A) = "&annee&" AND MONTH(A) = "&ROW(E4)-ROW(E$4)& "GROUP BY MONTH(A)",1),2,1)+0,0)

However I'd like to be more precise and also sum by month + type. So basically I'd like to add a query to search in another column if the data is matching what I ask to match, and, if so, sum the column I.

I'm sorry don't hesitate to tell me if I'm not precise enough.
Thanks everyone.

Thank you in advance

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Hello! You could set a query that itself brings the months and types, grouping them as you need. But if you have pre-written cells that you need to fill with sums you'd probably find an easier use with SUMIFS. Share a copy of the spreadsheet with the desired result ;)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please edit your question and insert [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.